# Multiprecision Arithmetic; The Carry Flag

Tags: assembly, arithmetic

Intel 8085: I'm having big troubles understanding addition or subtraction with more than 16-bit numbers in Intel 8085:

1.) If I execute `ADC M` instruction then this should happen: (A)<--(A)+((H)(L))+(CY) , right? How can be 16-bit data (HL) transfered to 8-bit register (A)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can be 16-bit data (HL) transfered to 8-bit register (A)?

`M` is not the contents of the `HL` register.  `M` is *the 8-bit byte stored at the memory location* pointed to by the `HL` register.

Comment: So the byte is 8-bit ?

Comment: Of course.  That's what a byte is.

Comment: I mean, is the memory location 8-bit?

Comment: If you run a 8085 it's supposed to be 8 bit. There are architectures with different bit counts, but they are rare.

Comment: Yes, the `M` referred to in `ADC M` yields an eight bit number.  There are some 8085 instructions like `LHLD` which deal in 16 bit quantities, but that's not the case for `ADC M`.

Comment: @ThomasKilian : So if another microprocessors architecture is 16-bit, than that means that all memory space is 16-bit?

Comment: Yes and no. The CPU will read memory in bit-chunks. The story is somewhat too  complex for a comment. Different CPU architectures can use different bit chunks that need or need not to be bit aligned. Most archs. use 8 bit chunks on 8 bit alignment. 64ers will just read 64bit chunks and break them internally.